# I can't find a Mono setting for my computer

Tags: earbuds

I can only hear out of my right ear, meaning when I put my earbuds in, I can only hear the right earbud and I'm missing out on what is happening in the other.

If there is a way to solve this, please help.

Comment: On some older computers especially, earbuds with microphones don't line up well with the connections in the plug. Try gently pulling out on the plug while listening for sound in the other ear - this has worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You need a Stereo to Mono adaptor. Its a cheap/common arrangement of plastic and metal, that looks vaguely like a headphone jack that dosen't have a cable attached, and roughly as platform agnostic as it gets. You're probably looking for a generic 3.5mm to 3.5mm one, though RCA to 3.5mm and RCA to RCA versions exist as well. As its generic and probably cheap as chips - I'll [point you at google](https://www.google.com.sg/search?sclient=psy-ab&client=firefox-b-ab&biw=2560&bih=1407&noj=1&q=3.5mm%20stereo%20to%20mono%20converter&oq=3.5mm%20stereo%20to%20mono%20converter&gs_l=serp.3..0i7i30k1l2j0.6525.8005.1.8247.7.5.2.0.0.0.104.449.4j1.5.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.6.348...0i8i7i30k1.SijnbSIzu0U) to find an appropriate model for your needs

[image]

If you don't mind additional software [voicemeeter banana](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/banana.htm) seems to do this on windows(along with other things.)

These settings work for me, making sure to pick my speakers as audio out (click on A1, and use that to pick the appropriate source). Its donationware and may have some nags but it seems to work great with very little fuss for a software solution for making your audio mono.

[image]

Comment: Is there any other application for downmixing all audio on your computer to mono, or is it just for accessibility purposes?

Comment: Well, honestly, I have no practical use for this. I just happened to be messing about with this on a different project that happened to use banana and I realised this would work. I don't even remember what the project *was*